# Is casting a null pointer to a reference defined behavior?

Tags: c++, casting, reference, null, undefined-behavior

I have this piece of C++ code:

```cpp
int main() {
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int& ref = reinterpret_cast<int&>(ptr);
    return ref;
}
```

While compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on both compilers, neither Clang nor GCC diagnose the cast, and only GCC diagnoses that I dereference a null pointer.

Is the cast from `ptr` to `ref` undefined behaviour? Or is only the read from `ref` in the return statement UB?

Comment: Casting pointer to reference is UB already, regardless of the value of the pointer. `reinterpret_cast` is widely considered as a way to tell compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing". So it doesn't produce diagnostics even on clearly wrong code.

Comment: I suppose the question is, what defined behaviour were you expecting from this code? It's hard to imagine what it might be.

Comment: It's equivalent to `*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&ptr))`, which should be clear by now that the value of `ptr` does not matter, as Yksisarvinen commented. Even if the `ptr` has a value that makes `*ptr` perfectly valid, what you are doing is still UB.

Comment: I didn't expect this to be defined behaviour. I am just having a hard time finding the proper part of the standard that says it isn't.

I'm a little surprised that the cast is UB behavior regardless of whether the pointer is null. I only did the `reinterpret_cast` to get around having to explicitly dereference the null pointer.

Comment: It is no different from `float f = 0; int & ri = reinterpret_cast<int&>(f);`, That `ptr` is a pointer does not change anything. Maybe what you really want to ask is different from what you have written in the code, but as the code is currently written, it has nothing to do with null pointer dereference.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is prove that references can never be null. It all started with [this exchange on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/18yujp3/what_would_you_consider_to_be_the_biggest_sin_in_c/kggamtj/), and my frustration that I couldn't get Clang to warn on code that seemed like it was trivially UB.

Comment: References can't be null. Null pointer dereference itself is part of a defect report and is not inherently UB, but binding a reference to that is UB. However this is not what the code in the question does.

Comment: So. I guess my actual question is: is there a way to create a null reference in C++? And if so, is that method ever defined behavior?

Do I edit this question or close it an ask the new one?

Comment: *is there a way to create a null reference in C++?*  Not in valid C++ code.  In ill-defined code, I'm sure you could get something to work like that (although it is more of a compiler implementation detail than defined by the language). *And if so, is that method ever defined behavior?*  No.  Although it could be implementation defined behavior, but I'm not aware of any implementation that would bother to define that behavior.

Comment: _"is there a way to create a null reference in C++?"_ [no](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#note-2).

Comment: There are no *null references* in C++.  In languages that have them it's because there are special language features to support them.  Now it's certainly possible to have *bad references*, and one of the easiest ways to get one is to dereference a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object, such as `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only GCC diagnoses that I dereference a null pointer.

That is not the warning I get when compiling your code. Instead I get

`warning: casting 'int*' to 'int&' does not dereference pointer`

This is a warning that there is no dereference, from a null pointer or otherwise.

> Is the cast from `ptr` to `ref` undefined behaviour?

The cast is perfectly valid by itself. This falls under point 6 of [cppreference.com's documenation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). A glvalue of type `int*` can be converted to a reference to another type, in this case `int`. The result is that of `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&ptr)`. That is, this cast causes `ref` to refer to the **value** of `ptr`, not (as you seem to think) to what that value points to.

If it was safe to access the reference, `ref` would start with the value zero (assuming the common case where a null pointer has all zero bits). If a new pointer was assigned to `ptr`, then the value of `ref` would also change, still assuming access was safe.

> Or is only the read from `ref` in the return statement UB?

An `int` is not allowed to alias a `int*`, so, yes, accessing the reference in the `return` statement yields undefined behavior. The same would be true if `ptr` had been initialized with `int* ptr = new int;` – whether or not the pointer is null has no bearing.

Comment: Your right, I got that warning twice and I must have assumed the second one was about `return ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, references are never supposed to be `nullptr`. The fact that you used a `reinterpret_cast` should tell you all you need to know already.